# SED occurrence specification beyond 9

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed, truncation

I am trying to do an operation to truncate or reintroduce special characters in a string. So I have decided to use sed for this operation. However, the occurrence specification doesn't seem to work after 9:

The string is:

dotLessLogName - /FTTIPIFT1FT751632ADRR262521251T-2521251-01Y20120925_102339csvgz

My sed command:

```
echo "$dotLessLogName" | sed 's/\([/]\{1\}\)\([A-Z]\{2\}\)\([A-Z]\{4\}\)\([A-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{1\}\)\([A-Z]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([A-Z]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{7\}\)\([A-Z]\{1\}\)\([-]\{1\}\)\([0-9]\{7\}\)\([-]\{1\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([A-Z]\{1\}\)\([0-9]\{8\}\)\([_]\{1\}\)\([0-9]\{6\}\)\([a-z]\{3\}\)\([a-z]\{2\}\)/\2,,\3,,\4\5,,\6\7\8\9,,\10,,\11,,\12,,\13,,\14,,\15,,\16,,\17,,\18,,\19,,\20,,\21/'
```

As you can see, I am trying to introduce ,, (to tabulate the fields separately in a CSV file)

However the output is:

```
FT,,TIPI,,FT1,,FT751632ADRR26,,/0,,/1,,/2,,/3,,/4,,/5,,/6,,/7,,/8,,/9,,FT0,,FT1
```

It seems to work alright first the first 9 instances, but after that it's going crazy!

Please can you help?

-Naga

Comment: Use awk or perl for this.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed, it appears, can only manage up to 9 back-references:
[[ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)]

> The *replacement* can contain *\n* (*n* being a number from 1 to 9, inclusive) references

You have a lot of captures you don't need, since you just concatenate them in the replacement. I'm going to do this in Perl, where the `m//` operator returns the captures as a list when in list context:

```
$ echo "$dotLessLogName" | perl -lne 'print join ",,",  m/\/([A-Z]{2})([A-Z]{4})([A-Z]{2}\d)([A-Z]{2}\d{6}[A-Z]{4}\d{2})(\d{7})([A-Z])(-)(\d{7})(-)(\d{2})([A-Z])(\d{8})(_)(\d{6})([a-z]{3})([a-z]{2})/'
FT,,TIPI,,FT1,,FT751632ADRR26,,2521251,,T,,-,,2521251,,-,,01,,Y,,20120925,,_,,102339,,csv,,gz
```

You did not include your desired output, please confirm this output.

Comment: Thank you anubhava and glenn, I have moved on and am now using awk instead.

Glenn - Thanks to you in particular. I will save this Perl code for my future reference.

Thank you both again.

-Naga